# Why is an exception thrown when trying to open a connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm getting an exception thrown in my C# code when opening a connection up. Visual Studio throws an exception saying 'The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.'. The odd thing is that the connection isn't open at all.

The weird thing is that the issue only occurs on one PC (PC-1).  On 2 other PCs (PC-2 and PC-3), the  code compiles and runs fine on those 2 other PCs, without any exception thrown. If I deploy to Azure from those PC-2 or PC-3, everything works.

All 3 PCs have same version of Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel), .NET (4.0.30319 SP1Rel), Azure 1.6 SDK, Azure Ap Fabric 1.5.37 and Azure tools for VS2010 (1.6.41103.1601)

Here's the pertinent part of the code:

```
   private long[] Foo(long rId, long mItemId)
    {
        List<long> list = null;

        using (myDBEntities ctx = new myDBEntities())
        {
            EntityConnection entityConnection = (EntityConnection)ctx.Connection;

            using (DbConnection connection = entityConnection.StoreConnection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                ...
```

Here is the full exception details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
Source=System.Data
StackTrace:
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
    at myPost.Models.Repository.Foo(Int64 rId, Int64 mItemId) in C:\code\Models\Repository.cs:line 326
    at myPost.Models.Repository.Foo(Int64 menuItemId, Int64 rId, mItemRatings[]& ratings, Photos[]& thumbnails) in C:\code\Models\Repository.cs:line 92
    at myPost.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String part1, String part2, String embed) in C:\code\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 97
    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
    at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
InnerException:
```

On the problem PC (PC-1), in order to get the code to run, I have to add in a `connection.Close();` right before the `connection.Open();`.  However, this breaks on PC-2 and PC-3, and even worse, when I deploy to Azure I get exceptions thrown because the `connection.Close()` I added wasn't necessary.

I have no idea what is wrong with the setup on PC-1 as it seems like a configuration problem, not a code issue.

Comment: Have you been connecting to the Azure instance from SQL Server MS from the first pc prior to executing the code?

Comment: No.  The only connection to Azure I have is from this project. It's the only code I'm running.

Comment: Did you create the connection string from the VS database wizard, that can also cause the same issue. If you build and deploy the application locally, not just from within VS, do you get the same issue?

Comment: I can only repro the issue when I deploy locally since the code will fail when I deploy to Azure.  On the problem PC, it's a new PC where I install VS2010, SP1, Azure SDK then loaded the code from subversion.  I'll try building and deploying locally to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed it's probably not a code issue. Just do a quick test on whether the connection is open or closed before proceeding - probably best to do that anyway. Something like:

```
if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
     // ahoy, mate!
}
else
{
    connection.Open();
    // here be dragons
}
```

I'm all about finding the Ghost in the Machine, but sometimes it's just easier to do a state check, and move on with your life.

Comment: I could do this, but I feel dirty in the process. I'd really like to get rid of the "Ghost"!